# Understanding Pointer to Pointer Logic in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I came across this code and was a bit confused on exactly what's going on here:

```
int **p;
p = malloc(sizeof(int *));
*p = malloc(sizeof(int));

**p = 10;


printf("%d\n",**p);
```

First of, p is a pointer to a pointer but it doesn't point to anything else, so why would we have to malloc twice here? Also in the first malloc call, why does one not need to have two pointer values around the p:
for instance:

```
**p = malloc(sizeof(int *));
```

instead of :

```
p = malloc(sizeof(int *));
```

I understand that the next line deference's the pointer and stores the value 10 in it, and then prints it. However I don't really get the previous lines, or at least why they're done in that frame of mind.

I'm used to seeing double pointers in this mindset:

```
int main(void) {
    int *ptr;
    int **ptr_ptr;

    ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *ptr = 5;
    ptr_ptr = &ptr;

    printf("%d\n",**ptr_ptr); /*prints 5*/

    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

As the double pointer actually points to something here. Any help with the first bit of code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your last piece of code is broken, you write `*ptr` but `ptr` is uninitialized

Comment: As in my last tidbit of code? It compiles on my system.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing `**p = malloc(sizeof(int *));` with `int **p = malloc(sizeof(int *));` In the first case, you are writing via a pointer that had not been initialised. In the second case, it's done all in one go, initialising `p`.

Comment: "p is a pointer to a pointer but it doesn't point to anything else" - if it was `int *p; p = malloc(sizeof(int));` then does `p` "point to anything else"?

Comment: @throw233 "compiles on my system" is no guarantee of correctness

Comment: I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `int **p` is a pointer to pointer, it will hold the location or address of an `int*` type of pointer. But one must first allocate enough memory for the `int*` which will be stored at the location pointed by `p`. This line does this job, it initializes `p`:

```
p = malloc(sizeof(int *));
```

Now, that `int*`'s location is known, one must allocate memory to store an acutal `int` at the memory pointed by `*p` which is our `int*` pointer. So another `malloc()` call is needed to initialize the `int*` type pointer.

```
*p = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

When all of it is done, an integer can be assigned to `**p`, which is the `int` pointed by `*p`:

```
**p = 10;
```

Comment: @throw233 You do not have to accept an answer at once. Generally it is good to wait at least a couple of hours before accepting one because there could be more detailed or simply better answers later on. If you have find some answer useful an upvote is good way to appriciate it, and you can accept the best later.

Comment: Yeah I figured, but for the moment, you go into a lot more detail.

Answer (score 0):

After the two mallocs, the variable p contains a pointer to a malloc-allocated pointer, which in turn contains a pointer to a malloc-allocated integer:

```
   +---+    +---+    +----+
p: |  ----> |  ----> | 10 |
   +---+    +---+    +----+
```

Comment: That makes sense, I guess it's not always that obvious.